# javascript keypress function: case-insensitive a-z, numbers and a few special chars?

Tags: jquery, regex, ajax

```
$('.s').keyup(function(e) {

    if (!/[A-Za-z0-9]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) {
        return false;
    }
```

I wonder what is the best regex solution for my application.
I have an ajax-based search that should just trigger the search when actual characters are pressed like a-Z (upper and lowercase), numbers and maybe a questionmark, a dash(hyphen), and an exclamation mark. Also the spacebar should be enabled.

Otherwise the ajax search would be triggered as well if the shift-, option, or control-key, is pressed.

What's the easiest regex pattern to understand here?
thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic form of your regex seems fine, just include what you want to include, and be aware of accented characters. Alternately, you might *exclude* the characters you *don't* want.

But I'd use the `keypress` event rather than `keyup` event for this. `keypress` fires when an actual typeable character is typed, and fires on key repeat (whereas you only get one `keyup` even if a key repeats). <s>`keypress` is not fired for Shift, Meta, Ctrl, etc.</s> **Update**: This isn't necessarily true cross-browser *(sigh)*, see the update below.

<s>If you're hooking `keypress`, I probably wouldn't filter anything out (no need for the regex), because I'd rather defer to the browser and its awareness of locale for what consitutes a real character.</s> I'd also probably include a brief delay so as to avoid lots of unnecessary searches. If the person fairly rapidly types "fred" there's no need to search on "f", "fr", and "fre".

Here's an example of what I mean (combining `keypress` with a slight delay). If you really want to filter out certain chars, you can do that in the event handler, but I haven't below for the reasons above:

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='theText'>
```

JavaScript (using jQuery, since you tagged your question with `jquery`):

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var searchTimer = 0;

  $('#theText').keypress(function() {
    if (searchTimer != 0) {
      clearTimeout(searchTimer);
    }
    searchTimer = setTimeout(doSearch, 250);
  });

  function doSearch() {
    searchTimer = 0;
    display("Search: '" + $('#theText').val() + "'");
  }

  function display(msg) {
    $('<p/>').html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});​
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ihegi)

That example searches a quarter second after the last `keypress` it sees; adjust the parameter to `setTimeout` as you see fit.

---

**Update**: After your comment below about arrow keys, I thought "but you don't see arrow keys on `keypress`, do you?" and the answer is: You do on Opera and a couple of others. *sigh* So yes, with a filter:

```
$('#theText').keypress(function(event) {
  // Magic numbers from http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 37: // Left
    case 38: // Up
    case 39: // Right
    case 40: // Down
      break;

    default:
      // A "real" key, include it
      if (searchTimer != 0) {
        clearTimeout(searchTimer);
      }
      searchTimer = setTimeout(doSearch, 250);
  }
});

function doSearch() {
  searchTimer = 0;
  display("Search: '" + $('#theText').val() + "'");
}
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ihegi/3) *(this one just filters out the arrow keys; you'll want to extend that)*

If you don't already know if it, [this page](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) is great for information around the madness that is keyboard events across browsers. It may be slightly dated.

Comment: where in the event handler can i filter certain chars? e.g. i don't want to fire the search with the arrow keys.

Comment: @user: I was going to say "You don't see arrow keys on `keypress`", but it turns out you do on some browsers. *sigh* Updated showing example of where and how you filter. :-)

Comment: I'm using firefox and keypress is fired when i hit the arrow keys on my mac. event.which returns 0 in my case so it does not really work. thanks anyway. i'll find a solution. the problem is that i actually need my arrow keys to navigate through the ajaxed search results. so i don't want to reload the searchresults when i hit the up or down key but rather jump between the list elements of my result: http://jsfiddle.net/zBjrS/1/

Comment: @user: I don't know how I ended up with `which` there, it should be `keyCode`; I tested with both and it was `keyCode` that was more reliable. *sigh* Copy and paste error, fixing... I can't speak for the Mac, but `keyCode` works correctly (where `which` does not) with Firefox and Opera on my Linux system.