# Problem with settimeout in jQuery with AJAX call

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I'm using jQuery AJAX call to dynamically display search results when a user types in a specified set of input boxes.  This code works fine and is identical to the **doSearch** function below, except that it binds directly to the "input.auto" keyup event.  But I'm trying to improve it by adding a time delay -- otherwise the call gets fired for each keyup event and some of the calls overlap which leads to very confusing results.

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577711/javascript-keypress-function-case-insensitive-a-z-numbers-and-a-few-special-cha) I came up with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var searchTimer = 0;

$('input.auto').keyup(function() {
    if (searchTimer != 0) {
      clearTimeout(searchTimer);
    }

    var length = $(this).val().length;
    searchTimer = setTimeout(doSearch(length), 250);
  });

function doSearch(length) {
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    // check to see if there are more than three characters in the input field
    if (length > 3) {
        //when user enters text, checks and retrieves matches
        $("#messages").hide();
        $("#messages").removeClass().addClass('loading').text('loading suggestions').fadeIn();
        var type = $(this).attr('id');
        switch (type) {
            // depending on type, different target urls are set
        }
        $.post(url,{ term:$(this).val() } ,function(data) {
            // if no suggestions are returned
            if (data=='No matches') {
                $("#messages").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() {
                    $(this).removeClass().addClass('failure').fadeTo(900,1).html(data);
                });
            // if suggestions are returned
            } else {
                $("#messages").removeClass().addClass('success').html(data).animate({height: '250px', opacity:'1'},{queue:false, duration:1500, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
            }
        });
     }
});
});
```

Perhaps there is a very simple thing here that I'm missing and it's demonstrating my hazy knowledge of jquery and javascript, but I would appreciate any pointers.  (Also, if somebody could explain what "searchtimer" does in this syntax, that would be great as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first arg to `setTimeout` is a function pointer but you're giving the result of the call to `doSearch`, change it to:

```
setTimeout(doSearch, 250);
```

and in `doSearch`, remove the `length` arg, as it's overridden by the local `length` var:

```
function doSearch() {
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    // check to see if there are more than three characters in the input field
    ...
```

`searchTimer` is an `id` for the timeout you fired. It's used to clear it later:

```
if (searchTimer != 0) {
      clearTimeout(searchTimer);
    }
```

this means that you can fire many timeOuts and keep trac of them one by one.

### Update:

`$(this)` in `var length = $(this).val().length` will refer to the `window object` not the curent `input`. You have to capture the `input element` and then pass it to the `doSearch function`:

```
$('input.auto').keyup(function() {
    if (searchTimer != 0) {
          clearTimeout(searchTimer);
        }
            searchTimer = setTimeout(doSearch(this), 250);
  });
```

replace `doSearch` by this one (and any use of `$(this)` in the function by `$(input)`):

```
function doSearch(input){
   return function(){
       searchTimer = 0;
       var length = $(input).val().length
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help -- although it's still not working.  The [original code](http://pastebin.com/FhqDBVY6) works, but [this code](http://pastebin.com/vQeuEXUT)  (based on your advice) doesn't do anything at all.  Any other tips?

Comment: `$(this)` in `length = $(this).val().length` will refer to the `window object` not the curent input. You have to capture the input and then pass it to the `doSearch` function. See my edit & this example in jsFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/hK8gP/1/

Comment: Finally figured it out -- forgot to change "this" to "input" in the doSearch function.  Thanks for the help and the intro to jsFiddle!